# How can I register my WindowController to be the first responder for a print operation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing

I have several nib files, and corresponding WindowController files for each of them. My NSMenu is declared in my main nib.

I understand that - print: (id) sender is called when the print command is selected from the menu, however, how can I register one of my WindowControllers to respond to that command when it is the active window?

Right now I'm not sure what is responding to the command, but a simple print window is appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Make any of the View in a window,you have to initialize the windows initialFirstResponder.
get into the inspector(tools-->inspector in xcode) for windows you have to link the view which you want to respond first,by linking the  connections-->outlets-->intialFirstResponder...

you can move the responders object by shifting nextKeyView attributes of the view